# .Distinct() clause not working c# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, distinct

I need to populate a dropdown list for for a number of views. The same drop down will be used to I wrote a Html Helper method to generate the contents of the dropdown.

```
    public static List<SelectListItem> GetBatchNumbers(this HtmlHelper html)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        ModelContainer ctn = new ModelContainer();

        var batchNumbers = ctn.SearchResults.OrderBy(x => x.BatchID).ToList();

        foreach (var batch in batchNumbers.Distinct())
        {
            items.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = batch.BatchID + "-" + batch.WebsiteName + "-" + batch.SourceName,
                Value = batch.BatchID
            });
        }

        return items;
    }
```

So in my test data, I have performed 3 batches of search results. So I want to see 3 batch numbers in the drop down list. However, I am seeing a batch number repeated for each entry in the SearchResults table, so the Distinct() clause appears not to be working in the desired way.

I've read that Distinct() is tricky with objects, does anyone know how I can achieve this another way?

Comment: What is SearchResult? Is it a class? Is it a struct? How is it loaded?

Comment: @Grumbler85 Search Result is a database table. It has 000's of entries, but I just want to retrieve the individual batchIDs, of which there should only be 3.

Comment: @Filip BatchID is a string.

Comment: Why don't you readed the batch-Table then?

Comment: @Grumbler85 There is no batch table surprisingly (I did not develop this). Your solution below did the trick for me however.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some implementations like `IEnumerable<obj>.DistinctBy(o => o.Prop)` which will support distinct by a special Property.

The following also works

```
list.GroupBy(l => l.Property).Select(group => group.First())
```

Comment: that did the trick. Thank you. I'll mark your answer as correct once the time limit is up.