# C# list -Eliminate Duplicate items by comparing specific properties

Tags: c#, linq, list, hashset

```
List<ClassA> newlist;
List<ClassA> oldlist;
```

`ClassA` has 20 different properties,
I want to

- compare and remove exact matching items from newlist
- however the comparison has to exclude few properties from `ClassA` as the values will not be relavant
- Record set I am dealing with is *huge* (300 thousand to 400 thousand). So it has to be *efficient*

Linq `Except` or `Intersect` doesnt seem to support the above requirement, plus it seems to be slow as well.
Any suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: just `.Distinct` with a custom comparer. If all relevant properties match - they are equal. Put the faster type comparisons first (ints, bools, etc) and slower ones last (strings, complex types), so in many cases you will find that elements are not equal before pulling out the heavy guns. Depending on your case, it might be better to actually hash all those relevant properties once per object and compare hashes before proceeding to compare actual values of the properties (assuming properties will not change value during the task)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement your own *custom comparer*

```
public class MyEqualityComparer: IEqualityComparer<ClassA> {
  public bool Equals(ClassA x, ClassA y) {
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
      return true;  
    else if ((null == x) || (null == y))
      return false;

    // Your custom comparison here (...has to exclude few properties from ClassA)  
    ... 
  }

  public int GetHashCode(ClassA obj) {
    if (null == obj)
      return 0;

    // Your custom hash code based on the included properties 
    ...
  }
}
```

and use `HashSet<ClassA>` then (we want to exclude `oldlist` from `newlist`):

```
HashSet<ClassA> toExclude = new HashSet<ClassA>(
   oldlist, 
   new MyEqualityComparer());

newList.RemoveAll(item => toExclude.Conytains(item));
```

Comment: thank you for the approach:) I am little confused, when I call MyEqualityComparer, I dont need to pass the new list?

Comment: @KeenUser: no, `MyEqualityComparer` is just a *custom rule* how to compare two `ClassA` instances for equality

Comment: You can, pobably, get rid of `oldlist` by reading recordset directy into `toExclude`

Comment: I would have to pass ClassA as parameter to MyEqualityComparer correct?

Comment: @KeenUser: you have to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` within `MyEqualityComparer` class. Net when working with `HashSet<ClassA>` will call these methods (on `ClassA` instances) when necessary.

Comment: Ok I only got a fair idea, excuse my naivety. I am not sure what kind of Custom Logic will go in GetHashCode? When will that be triggered?

Comment: @KeenUser: The simplest (and often quite a good implementation) is combining hashcodes of included properties with *xor*: `return obj.Property1.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Property2.GetHashCode() ^ ... ^ obj.PropertyN.GetHashCode();` if some properties vary a little (e.g. if, say, `Property10` almost always is `123`) you can remove it from hash computation.

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko Why not make use of HashSet's Except-Method?

Comment: @CSharpie: the question has been titled as "C# list -Eliminate Duplicate items...", that's why I've put `newList.RemoveAll(item => ...)`, if `newList` can be represented as `HashSet<ClassA>` then `Except` will be a good implmentation.

Comment: Can We customize Hashset Except as well to exclude few properties while comparing?

Comment: @KeenUser: you can customize *single method* `Except` in the similar way: `myset.Except(..., new MyEqualityComparer());`.

Comment: @KeenUser Its all about the EqualityComparer

Comment: @Dmitry Functionally it works absolutely correct! Do you think I can make this class MyEqualityComparer generic so that it can accept ClassA or ClassB(obviously the inside properties will vary based on the class)

Comment: @KeenUser: since `IEqualityComparer<T>` is generic sure you can implement it as generic class  `MyEqualityComparer<T>: IEqualityComparer<T>...`

Answer (score 0):

A while back, I found the following function which will allow you to distinct on a particular attribute.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
        if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
            yield return element;
}
```

I couldn't find the author for this, so thank you unnamed programmer!

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I am a little confused, How do I use specific properties here of two different list?

Comment: You want the distinct objects from the list, right?

Comment: Yes in a way distinct, But I want the list1 - matching items in list2. dont need distinct items in list2

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I misunderstood. I see Dmitry has a correct answer for you

Answer (score 0):

As described here: [.Distinct() clause not working c# MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211909/distinct-clause-not-working-c-sharp-mvc/16212086#16212086) you can use `GroupBy()` and `Distinct()` to archieve your Task.